# Регистро-зависимость в FormatConditions

Tags: vba, excel

Имеется код, задающий автоформат ячеек на весь лист:

```
Sub test (sToken As String, oPat As XlPattern, iPatCol As Integer, iCol As Integer)  
    Cells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:=sToken
    Cells.FormatConditions(Cells.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Cells.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .Pattern = oPat
        .PatternColorIndex = iPatCol
        .ColorIndex = iCol
    End With
    Cells.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

И всё работает прекрасно, пока не встречаются идентичные токены, но разнящиеся регистром.
 Напр. код вида:

```
Call test ("foo", xlPatternLightVertical, 4, 10)
```

Заформатит ячейки с "foo", "Foo", "fOo" итд...
Собственно вопросец: как заставить его учитывать регистр?

ЗЫЖ мну не сильно шпрехает в VBA, ниубивайте позязя =)

---

Сразу в вдогонку вариант:

```
Cells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlFormula, Formula1:=CBool(InStr(sToken, sCellValue))
```

Близок к идеалу, но... В `sCellValue` требуется передавать содержимое ячейки, которая будет форматироваться, но мы то работаем со всеми сразу. Возможно какая-то динамическая ссылка (вроде `Type:=xlCellValue`, где операции происходят как раз над содержимым, но тогда не совсем понятно, что использовать в `Formula1`)?

---

Итак, ответ таки найден =) Так-как 50 репы не имею, отвечу в вопросе.
Победить `FormatConditions` не вышло, но, перечитав тонну форумов, таки нашёл обходной путь: кастомные перехваты событий же!

1. Создаём `class module`, который и будет нашим обработчиком событий (в примере `clsWorksheetEventHandler`)
2. (Ш)Кодим:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Public WithEvents WorksheetEvents As Worksheet ' Как объект, события которого требуется перехватить
   Private Sub WorksheetEvents_Change(ByVal Target As Range) ' Собсно событие
       ' Тут могла быть ваша рек... то есть код-обробот  
   End Sub
   ```
3. В рабочем модуле пишем Сабы для включения/отключения обработчика(ов):

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Dim oWorksheetEventHandler As clsWorksheetEventHandler ' Представитель нашего класса
   Dim colWorksheetEventHandlers As Collection ' Сюда будем складировать сущности

   Sub WorksheetEventHandlers_initialize() ' Запуск перехвата
       ' Размечаем складские помещения
       Set colWorksheetEventHandlers = New Collection 
       ' Проходимся циклом по имеющимся инстансам, требующим перехвата событий
       For Each Worksheet In Worksheets
           ' Создаём инстанс обработчика
           Set WorksheetEventHandler = New clsWorksheetEventHandler 
           ' Заставляем работать
           Set WorksheetEventHandler.WorksheetEvents = Worksheet
           ' И запихиваем на склад
           colWorksheetEventHandlers.Add WorksheetEventHandler
       Next Worksheet
   End Sub

   Sub WorksheetEwentHandlers_terminate() ' Перехват выкл.
       'Проходимся по складу
       For Each WorksheetEventHandler In colWorksheetEventHandlers
           ' Убиваем рабочих (халтурили много, ага)
           Set WorksheetEventHandler = Nothing
       Next WorksheetEventHandler
       ' Взрываем склад
       Set colWorksheetEventHandlers = Nothing
   End Sub
   ```
4. ?????????????????????
5. PROFIT!!!!!!

Костыли, дааа. Но мну понравилось =)

---

ЗЫЖ пару полезных линков, на которых сиё безобразие выросло
[How to create application-level event handlers in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213566/en-us)
[Controlling multiple textboxes on a userform](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=80631)
[Тоже самое, но культурно и на ангельском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025326/case-sensitive-formatconditions-add/14063025#14063025) (а так же безуспешные попытки объясниться. Либо язык знаю худо, либо одно из двух)

Comment: чёт я намудрил с форматированием... а в окне предпросмотра кстати всё норм.